# How can I pass a variable from the content script to the page script in WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to pass my variable defined in my content script to the script that I inject into the web page. For example, I need to use an image defined in the content script like this:

```js
var myImage = browser.extension.getURL("myImage.jpg");
```

Then I inject some script from the content script to the loaded page as:

```js
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = browser.extension.getURL("myscript.js");
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

How can I access the variable "myImage" in the script "myscript.js"?

Comment: You can use CustomEvent messaging ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198)).

Answer (score 0):

you can use either `CustomEvent` or `window.postMessage`
and in `myscript.js` listen to the event or message.

**Example for window.postmessage**

```
window.postMessage({type: 'image-var', params: myImage }, "*");
```

in myscript.js

```
 window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        if (e.data.type === 'image-var') {
            console.log(e.data.params);
        }
    });
```

---

**Example for CustomEvent:**

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('yourCustomEvent', { detail: data }));
```

in myscript.js

```
document.addEventListener('yourCustomEvent', function (e) {
  var data = e.detail;
  console.log('received', data);
});
```